# How to pass a value from a textbox with type email to a function in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```
        <form id="form2" method="get" action="#">
            <table border="0" style="width: 800px; border: 0; padding: 16px; padding-left: 120px; vertical-align: central;">
                <tr>
                    <td>TP Email</td>
                    <td>:</td>
                    <td><input type="email" id="email2" size="40" maxlength="24"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Password</td>
                    <td>:</td>
                    <td><input type="password" id="password2" size="40"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td><button id="button2" onclick="myFunction();">Login</button>
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            function myFunction() {
                                var email2 = document.getElementById("email2").value;
                                alert(email2);
                                if (email2.toString() == 'illyam@gmail.com'){
                                    location.replace("admin.html");
                                }else{
                                    alert("Incorrect password or email");
                                }
                            }
                        </script></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>Do not have an account?<a href="sign_up.html" 
                    style="background-color: #E6E6E6; color: #CE171C;">Sign Up</a></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
```

This function is supposed to get a value from the textbox with id email2 and if it is equal to a certain value then it redirects to another page.

Comment: You shouldn't be using `onclick`. (It's obsolete). Use event listeners: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/api/eventlistener

Comment: You don't pass values from html to javascript. You can get values from the html using Javascript. I hope this helps.

Comment: The snippet you have shared is working for me. What issue are you facing?

Comment: whenever i type the correct email it does not redirect me to another page

Answer (score 0):

When you click Login button it should redirect to another page but you need to use **event.preventDefault() in your myFunction**.

**Try out the Code Below--**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="form2" method="get" action="#">
      <table
        
        style="
          width: 800px;
          border: 0;
          padding: 16px;
          padding-left: 120px;
          vertical-align: central;
        "
      >
        <tr>
          <td>TP Email</td>
          <td>:</td>
          <td><input type="email" id="email2" size="40" maxlength="24" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Password</td>
          <td>:</td>
          <td><input type="password" id="password2" size="40" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>
            <button id="button2" onclick="myFunction(event)">Login</button>
            <script type="text/javascript">
              function myFunction(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var email2 = document.getElementById("email2").value;
                alert(email2);
                if (email2.toString() == "illyam@gmail.com") {
                  location.replace("admin.html");
                } else {
                  alert("Incorrect password or email");
                }
              }
            </script>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>
            Do not have an account?<a
              href="sign_up.html"
              style="background-color: #e6e6e6; color: #ce171c"
              >Sign Up</a
            >
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

can pass values to JavaScript functions like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function myFunction(email) {

            if (email == 'illyam@gmail.com'){
                location.replace("https://admin.html")
               
                alert('redirecting to admin page')
            }else{
                alert("Incorrect password or email");
            }
           
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form2" method="get" action="#">
        <table border="0" style="width: 800px; border: 0; padding: 16px; padding-left: 120px; vertical-align: central;">
            <tr>
                <td>TP Email</td>
                <td>:</td>
                <td><input type="email" id="email2" size="40" maxlength="24"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password</td>
                <td>:</td>
                <td><input type="password" id="password2" size="40"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td><button id="button2" onclick="myFunction(document.getElementById('email2').value);">Login</button>
                   </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>Do not have an account?<a href="sign_up.html" 
                style="background-color: #E6E6E6; color: #CE171C;">Sign Up</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is to set the values inside the textbox and then get them as variables using JS.
You can have your HTML looking like this...

```
<td><button id="button2" onclick="myFunction(event);">Login</button></td>
```

And then have your JS script tag placed below your closing form tag like this...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var email2 = document.getElementById("email2").value;
        if(email2.toString() == 'illyam@gmail.com'){
            location.replace("admin.html");
        }else{
            alert("Incorrect password or email");
        }
    }
</script>
```

Your HTML onclick function now passes 'event' as an argument, this event object will be used in your script to cancel the normal form submission operation while you get your email values and evaluate them.
This is achieved with the help of event.preventdefault() function which stops the default qoperation of a form which is to submit information.

Side Note: I'd recommend that you use PHP and database for login purposes, having your login credentials in your script like this is dangerous as someone can easily go through your code and see them.

Good luck on your project.